# Bug in rhino CodeGenerator Token.EXPR_RESULT?

Tags: javascript, rhino

I'm currently looking at the code for Rhino 1.7.5 and 1.7.6.

In `CodeGenerator.java` is this code ([line 380+](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/CodeGenerator.java#L380)):

```
      case Token.EXPR_VOID:
      case Token.EXPR_RESULT:
        updateLineNumber(node);
        visitExpression(child, 0);
        addIcode((type == Token.EXPR_VOID) ? Icode_POP : Icode_POP_RESULT);
        stackChange(-1);
        break;
```

`child` is ([line 232](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/CodeGenerator.java#L232)):

```
Node child = node.getFirstChild();
```

[`ExpressionStatement`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ast/ExpressionStatement.java) is the node which triggers the `case` above
but it never calls `addChildToBack()` which would set `first` to anything.

So when the code above is executed, `child` is null and I get a `NullPointerException` in `CodeGenerator.visitExpression(Node, int)`

I can't see how this code could ever work. But at the same time, it's such a core feature that I can't imagine how people could have missed it for 6 years.

**[EDIT]** I managed to create a test case:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Parser;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ast.ScriptNode;

public class RhinoTest {

    @Test
    public void testCompileExpression() throws Exception {
        String expression = "row[\"COL_Col1\"]";
        CompilerEnvirons compilerEnv = new CompilerEnvirons();
        Parser p = new Parser( compilerEnv, compilerEnv.getErrorReporter() );
        ScriptNode script = p.parse( expression, null, 0 );

        Interpreter compiler = new Interpreter( );
        Object compiledOb = compiler.compile( compilerEnv, script, null, false );
        assertNotNull( compiledOb );
    }
}
```

If I run this, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CodeGenerator.visitExpression(CodeGenerator.java:497)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CodeGenerator.visitStatement(CodeGenerator.java:383)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CodeGenerator.visitStatement(CodeGenerator.java:276)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CodeGenerator.generateICodeFromTree(CodeGenerator.java:113)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CodeGenerator.compile(CodeGenerator.java:83)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.compile(Interpreter.java:194)
    at com.avanon.basic.birt.RhinoTest.testCompileExpression(RhinoTest.java:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of the AST API, code generation needs an additional step to convert the "raw" parse tree into something suitable for codegen.

To fix the test case above, change the line:

```
    ScriptNode script = p.parse( expression, null, 0 );
```

into:

```
    ScriptNode ast = p.parse( expression, null, 0 );

    IRFactory irf = new IRFactory(compilerEnv, compilerEnv.getErrorReporter());
    ScriptNode tree = irf.transformTree(ast);
```

You can also find examples how to prepare for codegen in [`Context.compileImpl()`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.java#L2442)